# Generic way to run code on existing (main) thread in android?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a module which is currently being used to for an android app, but is meant to work as a generic java module. At some point it does some work on a background thread, and needs to them provide a callback that runs on the original thread (in this case, the main thread in android). I know that some combination of android specific `Looper`'s and `Handler'`s can be used to accomplish this in android. But is there a more generic way to do this that will work in an android app, as well as a generic java application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no *general* way in Java to "run code on another thread."

Every thread starts by calling a `run()` method.  From then on, until the thread dies, it will only do what that run() method tells it to do.

There are special cases:  For example, the run() method of a thread pool *worker thread* tells the thread to pick tasks off a queue and execute them.  Some other thread can make the worker thread call some arbitrary function, f(), by putting a task that calls f() into the queue.  But that only works because of how the worker's run() method was written.

The `run()` method (and whatever else it calls, of course), totally controls the thread.